# Palindrome (euler project)

Tags: python, python-2.7, palindrome

I am trying solve this problem with Python:

"**Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.**" This is my code:

```
list_number = reversed(range(10000, 998002))


def check_number(x): 
    for element in reversed(range(100, 1000)):
        while True:
            if x >= 100:
                if element * x == i:
                    print(i)
                    break
                else:
                    x -= 1
                    continue
            else:
                break


for i in list_number:    
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        check_number(999)
    else:
        continue
```

The code works with 2-digit numbers but not with 3-digit numbers.
Can someone pleas tell me what is incorrect?

Comment: For info, you can do `range(998002, 10000, -1) to step down through a range.

Comment: Yeah I already know that but I am still new so I try different things

Comment: Also the loop uses `i` but this isn't defined anywhere - what is this meant to be?

Comment: for i in list_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is extremely badly written, but the real problem is in the statement `x -= 1`: The value of `x` is decremented at each iteration of the inner loop and at the end of the *first* inner loop, `x` is 99. This makes the condition `if x >= 100` false for all consequent iterations of the outer loop.

Add `x=999` immediately after `for element in reversed(range(100, 1000))`. Or, better, learn some good programming and rewrite the program entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am still a beginner so I am still learning, I know the code is not perfect but I learn python since a few weeks, I'll try to improve the code a bit!